# I can't pass an object that is the same as the parameter(flutter)

Tags: flutter

This is my code, I'm using SQlite as my db. I made the model and the databaseHelper, I just don't know what's happening I just cant pass a User object to the insertUser in which have the User parameter

```
User user = new User(firstName.text,lastName.text,emailAddress.text,username.text,password.text);
                              dataBaseHelper.insertUser(user);
dataBaseHelper.insertUser(user);
```

This is the insertUser function from the databaseHelper

```
Future<int> insertUser(User user) async{
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.insert(tableName, user.toMap());
    return result;
  }
```

The error

```
lib/Pages/Login_Registration/registration.dart:143:57: Error: The argument type 'User/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User/*2*/'.
 - 'User/*1*/' is from 'package:paraiso/Models/users_model.dart' ('lib/Models/users_model.dart').
 - 'User/*2*/' is from 'lib/Models/users_model.dart'.
                              dataBaseHelper.insertUser(user);
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes!

lib/Pages/Login_Registration/registration.dart:143:57: Error: The argument type 'User/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User/*2*/'.
 - 'User/*1*/' is from 'package:paraiso/Models/users_model.dart' ('lib/Models/users_model.dart').
 - 'User/*2*/' is from 'lib/Models/users_model.dart'.
                              dataBaseHelper.insertUser(user);

Comment: Remove the User import from both classes and import again. This import path error is quite common in dart.

Comment: @Luiz ah yes, I once had this problem and ended up sitting in a corner crying...

Comment: @AquilinoCagubcub please edit the post to include the error message in the body of the question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are importing two different types of users.

Make sure that the User you are inserting into the method insertUser() is of the same type as the one that you are expecting in that method.

```
import 'lib/Models/users_model.dart';
```

should be used in both classes

Comment: Oh thank you! I see the problem, on the database_helper I import same class but it has a different path. This is from database_helper import 'file:///D:/Dev/Flutters/Loloy/paraiso/lib/Models/users_model.dart';, and this is from the registration class, import 'package:paraiso/Models/users_model.dart';

Comment: it seems that the database_helper use full path which is clearly a problem. Thank you soo much!